# 8 way demultiplexer hdl not working

Tags: multiplexer, hdl

I am trying to make a 8 way demultiplexer in hdl. The hdl is nog vhdl or verilog. It is interpreted specially for a [nand2tetris](http://nand2tetris.org) cursus.

I try to get something like this

```
| in  |  sel  |  a  |  b  |  c  |  d  |  e  |  f  |  g  |  h  |
|  1  |  000  |  1  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
|  1  |  001  |  0  |  1  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
|  1  |  010  |  0  |  0  |  1  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
|  1  |  011  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  1  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
|  1  |  100  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  1  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
|  1  |  101  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  1  |  0  |  0  |
|  1  |  110  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  1  |  0  |
|  1  |  111  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  1  |
```

Instead I get this:

```
| in  |  sel  |  a  |  b  |  c  |  d  |  e  |  f  |  g  |  h  |
|  1  |  000  |  1  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
|  1  |  001  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  1  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
|  1  |  010  |  0  |  0  |  1  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
|  1  |  011  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  1  |  0  |
|  1  |  100  |  0  |  1  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
|  1  |  101  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  1  |  0  |  0  |
|  1  |  110  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  1  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
|  1  |  111  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  1  |
```

I can't find anything wrong with my hdl code. Maybe I have overlooked something? Does somebody see a reason it doesn't work.

My hdl program looks like this:

```
CHIP DMux8Way {
    IN in, sel[3];
    OUT a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h;

    PARTS:
    // Put your code here:
    Not(in=sel[0], out=notSel0);
    Not(in=sel[1], out=notSel1);
    Not(in=sel[2], out=notSel2);

    And4Way(a=notSel0, b=notSel1, c=notSel2, d=in, out=a);
    And4Way(a=notSel0, b=notSel1, c=sel[2], d=in, out=b);

    And4Way(a=notSel0, b=sel[1], c=notSel2, d=in, out=c);
    And4Way(a=notSel0, b=sel[1], c=sel[2], d=in, out=d);     

    And4Way(a=sel[0], b=notSel1, c=notSel2, d=in, out=e);
    And4Way(a=sel[0], b=notSel1, c=sel[2], d=in, out=f);

    And4Way(a=sel[0], b=sel[1], c=notSel2, d=in, out=g);
    And4Way(a=sel[0], b=sel[1], c=sel[2], d=in, out=h);
}
```

Comment: hah! somehow you swapped the bits around in "sel". I'm not reading that code to find the actual mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are swapping bits. For example, for b you wrote:

```
And4Way(a=notSel0, b=notSel1, c=sel[2], d=in, out=b);
```

whereas it should be

```
And4Way(a=Sel[0], b=notSel1, c=notSel2, d=in, out=b);
```

And even better, to avoid further confusion, write the code like this:

```
And4Way(c=notSel2, b=notSel1, a=Sel[0], d=in, out=b);
```